# How do I tell if OpenLDAP is installed on CentOS, and test that it's working?

Tags: centos, ldap, openldap, testing

What's the easy way to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
yum list installed
```

will show you if it's installed.

```
chkconfig --list
```

will show you if the service is running (might be called slapd)

Config will be somewhere like /etc/openldap/* and you can see if it's been configured.

Test it by querying it with something like:

```
ldapsearch -x -b 'dc=mycompany,dc=com' 'objectclass=*'
```

but you might have to know how it's (supposed to be) configured to know what to search for.

http://home.roadrunner.com/~computertaijutsu/ldap.html

Comment: **@TessellatingHeckler:** Thanks, very high quality answer!! Cheers!!

Answer (score 4):

Another way would be:

```
pidof slapd
```

If this results in an integer (the PID of the process), you have a running OpenLDAP server. If there is no output, it's not running.